# Magic state distillation, eigenvectors of Clifford gates, and transversal gates

Tags: error-correction, stabilizer-code, clifford-group, fault-tolerance, magic-states

I have some (possibly mistaken) ideas about magic state distillation. Please disabuse me of them?

In [section III "Universal Quantum Computation with Magic States" of the original paper on magic states](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0403025), Bravyi and Kitaev give a protocol using Clifford gates that takes in one qubit of unknown logical information $$|\psi\rangle=\alpha |0\rangle+ \beta |1\rangle\,, $$ in the first register and the eigenstate $$ |H\rangle= \cos(\frac{\pi}{8})|0\rangle+\sin(\frac{\pi}{8})|1\rangle $$ of the Hadamard gate $ H $ in the second register and outputs the gate $$ T= \begin{bmatrix} 1& 0 \\ 0 & e^{i \pi/4} \end{bmatrix}\,, $$ applied to $ |\psi\rangle $ in the first register (the output of the second register is discarded). This is notable because the protocol uses only Clifford gates and the eigenstate $ |H\rangle $ but is able to apply a non-Clifford gate $ T $ to the given quantum information.

Later in the same section Bravyi and Kitaev give a protocol using Clifford gates that takes in one qubit of unknown logical information $$|\psi\rangle=\alpha |0\rangle+ \beta |1\rangle\,, $$ in the first register and the eigenstate $ |F\rangle $ of the facet gate in the second register and outputs the gate $$  \begin{bmatrix} 1& 0 \\ 0 & e^{i \pi/6} \end{bmatrix}\,, $$ applied to $ |\psi\rangle $ in the first register (the output of the second register is discarded). This is notable because the protocol uses only Clifford gates and the eigenstate $ |F\rangle $ but is able to apply a non-Clifford gate $ \begin{bmatrix} 1& 0 \\ 0 & e^{i \pi/6} \end{bmatrix} $ to the given quantum information.

How do you get the eigenstate $ |H\rangle $ of the Hadamard gate? Is it true that you can distill $ |H\rangle $ from any $ d\geq 2 $ stabilizer code with transversal $ H $? For example, the $ [\![4,2,2]\!] $ quantum repetition code or the $ [\![15,7,3]\!] $ quantum Hamming code?

How do you get the eigenstate $ |F\rangle $ of the facet gate? Is it true that you can distill $ |F\rangle $ from any $ d\geq 2 $ stabilizer code with transversal $ F $? For example, the $ [\![5,1,3]\!] $ code?